# Disable and enable on click on date calendar icon

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, development, jquery, metadata

I am trying to make the date field calendar icon unclickable in some scenarios, which I manage by using this:

```
$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_EditModePanel1_ctl01_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDateDatePickerImage").click( function () { return false; } )
```

And then in another scenario I want the link to be clickable again, so I tried this

```
$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_EditModePanel1_ctl01_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDateDatePickerImage").click( function () { return true; } )
```

Also tried to make it clickable again with a lot of other commands I found on google, but the link stays unclickable.

How can I make a link I made unclickable clickable again ?
Please advice

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would be by using the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) css property.

**Disable the calendar link:**

```
$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_EditModePanel1_ctl01_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDateDatePickerImage").parent().css("pointer-events", "none")
```

**Enable the calendar link:**

```
$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_EditModePanel1_ctl01_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDateDatePickerImage").parent().css("pointer-events", "initial")
```